# Azure Devops App Service Deploy Task Not Work Suddenly

Tags: azure-devops, sitecore

I use [Azure App Service deploy] task in Azure Devops pipeline to deploy the artifact to an Azure App service.

Everything worked well before but today it not work suddenly. It failed when i tried to deploy the artifact to the production slot (the slot marked production). But when i tested to deploy to deployment slots, it worked well.

I just got an error message that has no much detail in the log

```
Cleaning up temp folders from previous zip deployments and extracting pushed zip file C:\local\Temp\zipdeploy\534hsvxr.zip (80.94 MB) to C:\local\Temp\zipdeploy\extracted
[error]Failed to deploy web package to App Service.
[error]Error: Package deployment using ZIP Deploy failed. Refer logs for more details.
```

Anyone got the same issue before?
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

It seems to be a source control issue. Just try going to the App Service `Deployment Center` blade and click "`Disconnect`" to disconnect your deployment. And then try to deploy it again.

[image]

Comment: I have no idea why it worked but it worked lol. Thank you very much!